# Is it more common to use $n \times m$ or $m \times n$ for matrices?

Tags: matrices

I've seen both versions for representing the number of rows by the number of columns of a matrix. I've always used $n \times m$, but I feel like I more often see $m \times n$. Is there some well known standard that people typically follow?

Comment: When the decision is arbitrary alphabetical order is more common. I hesitate to call any notation standard.

Comment: Maybe I should use $m*n$ with the order in accordance with the alphabetical order

Comment: @CyclotomicField I shouldn't have standard because I know there isn't a standard (otherwise would've found it on Google). I just feel that I see $m \times n$ more often probably for the reason you state. I don't know why I adopted the reverse ABC order notation.

Answer (score 2):

I always use $r\times c$ personally. It stops the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

When one needs to represent a (single) natural number, "$n$" seems to be a pretty common choice.  If another integer variable is needed, lots of people would choose "$m$". Since "$n$" came first, it might be sensible to use $n\times m$.

The same dilemma  takes place when dealing with parameters for curves, as "$t$" (for time) is a natural first choice, "$s$" coming in second place.